# How to order one legend according to another legend in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two different datasets but with the same label names. After i plotted both plots, I found that the legends are not in the same order, and the colour were different too. Wonder what I should do to make sure they are consistent?

[image]

Thank you very much!!

Comment: If your variables are factors you can solve this by having the factor levels in both variables come in the same order.

Comment: @Luis Thank you very much, I took your suggestion and it works !
And I found this piece of information useful, hope anyone searched for the same thing could take a look of this too:
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Changing_the_order_of_levels_of_a_factor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `factor` to set the order of the `levels` and `labels` in both datasets.

```
require(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(
    cyl, 
    levels = c("4", "6", "8"), 
    labels = c("Four", "Six", "Eight"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(disp, drat, color = cyl)) + 
  geom_point()

df2 %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(
    cyl, 
    levels = c("4", "6", "8"), 
    labels = c("Four", "Six", "Eight"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(disp, drat, color = cyl)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Result: 
[image]
[image]

Sample data:

```
df1 <- select(mtcars[1:10, ], cyl, disp, drat)

df2 <- select(mtcars[11:20, ], cyl, disp, drat)
```